# Ionic app not issuing POST request

Tags: django, ionic-framework

I have an interesting problem with my Ionic application with a Django API server backend.

In previous versions of my app (0.0.1-.0.0.5) this hasn't come up, but starting now I'm not able to issue a POST request to get my authentication token.

Using Ionic locally `ionic serve` against my deployed server, when I attempt a login, my server registers an `OPTIONS /token-auth/` and then `POST /token-auth/`. When I run the application on my device `ionic run android` and attempt to login the server only registers the OPTIONS request but does not register the POST, according to the server logs.

I've found out this is due to CORS, it issues an OPTIONS first to see what it is allowed to issue. For some reason the OPTIONS request comes back with absolutely nothing. In my other Django Rest Framework projects, the OPTIONS comes back with a proper response. I think this is related, but it's strange that it works from localhost to the deployed server with the OPTIONS request responding the same.

My login function is pretty basic:

```
$http({ 
  method: 'POST',
  url: config.apiUrl + 'token-auth/',
  data: {
    "username": usernameElement[0].value,
    "password": passwordElement[0].value
  }
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log('success', data);
  ...
}, function(err) {
  console.log('error', err);
  ...
});
```

Another thing I find interesting is that it runs the error function but instead of giving me back a normal error object in the `err` variable, I get back what appears to be the request object. I have never seen this before.

```
{
  "data":null,
  "status":0,
  "config":{
    "method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],
    "transformResponse":[null],
    "url":"http://example.com/api/token-auth/",
    "data":{
      "username":"myuser",
      "password":"mypassword"
    },
    "headers":{
      "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}
    },
  "statusText":""
}
```

- Runs fine local app to deployed server
- Device app to deployed server doesn't register POST request, only OPTIONS
- AJAX error return is the request object, not the error response object

I've been stuck on this for a couple days now and am looking for any ideas.

Comment: Did you add the URL to the whitelist? http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist

Comment: @cDima hey yeah cordova whitelist is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was in fact a CORS problem. After debugging through [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) I found that it was not passing the CORS. I later found out that instead of serving on http://192.168.1.**36**:8100 for some reason ionic switched to serve on http://192.168.1.**10**:8100